# grep exact match excluding certain terms

Tags: r, regex

Help apprecited. I've got a long list of column names in a vector, where the pattern is like this:

```
cols <-c('a35-male-x1','a35-female-x2','a16-male-t0','a65-female-t7',...)
```

I've tried using grep to find the columns with 'male' matches, but exclude the female ones.

```
grep(pattern='male',cols)
```

will get all 4 entries. Is there a simple way to get this done in grep? Or a better approach using some other function? 
Thanks in advance,  p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word boundary i.e `\\b` to match only 'male'

```
grep('\\bmale\\b', cols, value=TRUE)
#[1] "a35-male-x1" "a16-male-t0"
```

For this example,

```
grep('-male-', cols)
#[1] 1 3
```

would also work

#### data

```
 cols <-c('a35-male-x1','a35-female-x2','a16-male-t0','a65-female-t7')
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative (considering you only have `male` or `female`):

```
Filter(function(u) !grepl('female',u), cols)
#[1] "a35-male-x1" "a16-male-t0"
```

Or simply:

```
cols[!grepl('female',cols)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<!fe)male
```

You can use the with `perl=True` option to get exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach

```
grep("[^female][male]", cols, value = TRUE)
#[1] "a35-male-x1" "a16-male-t0"
```